# fopen on URL blocks script execution in PHP

Tags: php, stream, nonblocking

I'm trying to open a non-blocking stream in PHP (5.3.2 & 5.4.4). I do the following:

```
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');
if ($fp === false)
    return false;
print('stream opened'.PHP_EOL);
stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
```

The url points to a php file:

```
<?php sleep(10); ?>
<html><body>Hello</body></html>
```

The problem is that fopen() seems to block before I am even able to setup the stream as non blocking. Indeed, the `stream opened` message is printed after 10 seconds and not directly.

Comment: According to the docs on `stream_set_blocking`, it only supports sockets and regular files. Your URL resource is neither of those.

Comment: Isn't a TCP connection a socket stream? Anyway, it is the fopen that blocks here (i read the message 'stream opened' after 10 sec), not the freads().

Comment: Your `fopen` is waiting for a handshake to occur from your URL. It's waiting 10 seconds because your PHP script has a `sleep(10)`. A stream requires a handshake and then a persistent open connection. Your PHP script is waiting the 10 seconds, sending a response and immediately closing the connection. This is default behavior for PHP. You can make a socket stream using PHP but its not going to be a two-line napkin script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a `fopen` on a url, the HTTP headers are sent at that moment. Since no context has been defiened (and it is not possible to configure contexts with the non-blocking option), `fopen` waits for the http headers to be sent and blocks.
A workaround is to use `fsockopen` which only opens the tcp connecion and does nothing more. The drawback of this approach is that the HTTP request has to be created manually.

Here is an (optimizable) implementation that reads data from an url in a non blocking way.

```
function parse_http_url($url)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if ($parts === false) return false;
    if (!isset($parts['scheme']))
        $parts['scheme'] = 'http';
    if ($parts['scheme'] !== 'http' && $parts['scheme'] !== 'https')
        return false;
    if (!isset($parts['port']))
        $parts['port'] = ($parts['scheme'] === 'http') ? 80 : 443;
    if(!isset($parts['path']))
        $parts['path'] = '/';
    $parts['uri'] = $parts['path'];
    if (!empty($parts['query']))
        $parts['uri'] .= '?'.$parts['query'];
    return $parts;
}

function url_get_contents($url, $options = null) {
    if(!($url_parts = parse_http_url($url))) return false;
    $timeout = intval(@$options['http']['timeout']);
    if (!($fp = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], $url_parts['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout))) return false;
    stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
    if($timeout > 0) {
        stream_set_timeout($fp, $timeout);
        $sleep_time = (($timeout * 1000000) / 100); # 1% of timeout in ms
        $stop_time = microtime(true) + $timeout;
    } else {
        $sleep_time = 10000; # 10 ms
    }
    if (!isset($options['http']['method'])) $options['http']['method'] = 'GET';
    if (!isset($options['http']['header'])) $options['http']['header'] = '';
    $request = "{$options['http']['method']} {$url_parts['uri']} HTTP/1.1\r\n{$options['http']['header']}\r\n";
    if (fwrite($fp, $request) === false) {
        fclose($fp);
        return false;
    }
    $content = '';
    $buff_size = 4096;
    do {
        $rd = fread($fp, $buff_size);
        if ($rd === false) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }

        $content .= $rd;

        $meta = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
        if ($meta['eof']) {
            fclose($fp);
            if(empty($content)) return false;
            // HTTP headers should be separated with \r\n only but lets be safe
            $content = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $content);
            $resp = explode(' ', array_shift($content));
            $code = isset($resp[1]) ? intval($resp[1]) : 0;
            if ($code < 200 || $code >= 300) {
                $message = isset($resp[2]) ? $resp[2] : 'Unknown error';
                trigger_error("Error {$code} {$message}", E_USER_WARNING);
                return false;
            }
            // Skip headers
            while (!empty($content) && array_shift($content) !== '');
            return implode("\n", $content);
        }
        if ($meta['timed_out']) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($stop_time) && microtime(true) >= $stop_time) {
            fclose($fp);
            return false;
        }

        if ($meta['unread_bytes'] === 0) {
            usleep($sleep_time);
        }
    } while(true);
}
```